# Get the description of the xml file from xsl template

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

Is it possible, having a ready xsl template, to get from it a description of the xml file that this template expects to convert to pdf?

Answer (score 0):

It is normally possible to reverse-engineer at least part of the XML structure from a given XSLT (Example: [Reverse-Engineering unknown XML based on known XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731630/reverse-engineering-unknown-xml-based-on-known-xsl)).

It helps if the template is specific, i.e. using absolute paths, type converstions, only simple XPath conditions and reversible functions.

However, I am not aware of any software available for this task, you probably have to do it manually.